# How quick are you able to set the exposure on the Sony NEX-C3 (or other cameras like it)?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, exposure, sony, camera-settings

#### Background

I am considering the NEX-C3 as a nice camera to take on trips\shoots\vacation\outing\etc where my DSLR would be too large but I do not want to sacrifice my ability to set the exposure of my shots. I know it is possible, but I am concerned how quickly I am able to achieve it.

#### How can I?

My main flow with my DSLR is to have it set in aperture priority so that the front wheel operates the aperture and the back wheel changes the exposure compensation (+/-). I've found this method ideal since I *mostly* trust the in camera meter but can **quickly** change the exposure to taste, all without pressing any buttons or digging through menus.

I know I will not be able to achieve this sort of speed on the NEX-C3. So my question is this, are you able to mimic this work flow without digging through menus or an excessive amount of button presses?

Or is there a workflow on the NEX-C3 that allows you to set exposure in a similar fashion but faster?

#### So...

I've picked the Sony NEX-C3 simply because it's the newest and has the largest sensor among it's competitors. But, if a competing camera in the same class is capable of doing what I described above please let me know.

Thanks in reading my long winded question!

Comment: If by cameras like it you include the Olympus E-P2, very quickly since it has a mode-dial and dual control-dials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a NEX-camera in Av, the back wheel selects an aperture unless you press "up" (on the combined d-pad/wheel) which will allow you to change exposure compensation. Not as quick as having two dials, but better than most P&S cameras. You could also configure the center button to allow quick access to ISO and metering mode, without having to delve into the menu.

The focus-peeking feature added in a recent firmware update (should be included from the start with the C3, IIRC) is really quite handy for macro work, since it gives you a nice, solid indication of the current DOF.

Comment: Awesome thanks! That appears quick since the wheel and pad are on top of each other.